# How to upload files in MVC asp.net core + update on sql server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to upload files in MVC dot net core 2, I am student and new to this technology (I read some q&a here, but no answer for this question).

I have a add action & view for my Product model. In the view, there is a form to create the product with some properties. I want also to add an option to upload image - after click on add button, the product need to be saved in the data base using Entity Framework code first.

I don't use ViewModel (and I don't want a solution with it), but maybe later I will want to create class for Image entity. Not now (Too much for me).

Please help me how to do it. Here is the code.

Model - Product:

```
public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Category { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Age { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool ConditionIsNew { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller - ProductController

```
public class ProductController : Controller
    {
            [HttpGet]
            public IActionResult Add()
            {
                return View(new Product());
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult Add(Product p)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    ProductDal dal = new ProductDal();
                    dal.Products.Add(p);
                    dal.SaveChanges();
                    return View("Show", p);
                }
                return View(p);
            }
    }
```

View - Add (Razor Syntax, tag helper)

```
@model MyProjectTest.Models.Product
    @{
        Layout = "~/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
<h1>Submit</h1>
    <h2>Add product</h2>
    <form asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Add" method="post">
            <label asp-for="Name"></label> <input asp-for="Name" /> <span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
            <br />
            <label asp-for="Description"></label> <input asp-for="Description" /> <span asp-validation-for="Description"></span>
            <br />
            <label asp-for="Category"></label> <input asp-for="Category" /> <span asp-validation-for="Category"></span>
            <br />
            <label asp-for="Gender"></label> <input asp-for="Gender" /> <span asp-validation-for="Gender"></span>
            <br />
            <label asp-for="Age"></label> <input asp-for="Age" /> <span asp-validation-for="Age"></span>
            <br />
            <label asp-for="ConditionIsNew"></label> <input asp-for="ConditionIsNew" /> <span asp-validation-for="ConditionIsNew"></span>
            <br />
            <input id="SubmitProduct" type="submit" value="Enter" />
        </form>
```

Again, I have no ViewModel and I don't want to use it.

I also want to know how to update the image to database

Thank you

Comment: You want to upload the image to sql server. am I right?

Comment: This is already documented in the docs: [File Uploads in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: do you want to save url in database or actually want to save image in database?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_file.asp

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/upload-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2

One thing that you need to know. Input will contain binary representation of uploaded file so you need to remember to deserialize/serialize it if you want to use it somehow.

Comment: Hi @Robert, I know how to make an input tag. But thanks :)

The razor pages you sent me is not what I need, this not same as MVC.

I also read the docs of Microsoft, but there is not answer for my question. here is the docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

Html layer:
* input type="file" name="fileABC"/>

Controller layer:
method html post with param of HttpPostedFileBase type and named fileABC (must by 
separate from parametr for model in this case Product model)

For SQL:
use blob, filestream ...